# How to change the color of one of my td when a confirm message appears with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my array, I have different options possible. When the user wants to delete a line, there is a pop-up message to confirm that you really want to delete the line. I want to highlight the selected line by adding a boostrap class like "danger". So, I tried to addClass("danger") when clicking on the button. The problem is that when the confirm message pops, the line is not colored.The class "danger" is only added  if I cancel to make the pop up message disappears. How can I change the color of the td BEFORE the pop up message appears?

For now, I just have :

```
<a href="javascript:addRed('<?=$_POST['class']?>',<?=$instance->getID()?>);deleteInstance('<?=$_POST['class']?>',<?=$instance->getID()?>)" class="text-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-times"></i></a>

function addRed(className,id) {
    var supprClass = className;
    var supprId = id;
$("#"+ supprClass + "_" + supprId).addClass("danger");
console.log("classe mise");
}

function removeRed(className,id) {
    var supprClass = className;
    var supprId = id;
    $("#"+ supprClass + "_" + supprId).removeClass("danger");
    console.log("classe enlevée");
}

function deleteInstance(className,id, )
{
    if(confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cet enregistrement ?\nOPERATION IRREVERSIBLE'))
    {
        $.blockUI();
        $.ajax
        ({
            url : 'action.php?action=deleteInstance',
            type : 'post',
            data : { 'class' : className, 'id' : id },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(response)
            {
                noty({ type : response.type, text : response.text });
                if(response.type=='success')
                    search();               
                $.unblockUI();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                noty({ type : 'error', text : 'Erreur lors de la suppression de l\'enregistrement.' });
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    }
    removeRed();
}
```

Sorry if I'm not very clear. I'm a beginner.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:deleteRow('<?=$_POST['class']?>',<?=$instance->getID()?>);" class="text-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-times"></i></a>

function deleteRow(className, id) {
    addRed(className, id);
    setTimeout(function () {
        deleteInstance(className, id);
    }, 500);
}
```

Your functions are maybe executed at the same time so you need to add a delay by the "setTimeout" function for the "deleteInstance" function.

For me, it is a best practice to call a unique function on your button which will call all the functions you need. It's why I added the "deleteRow" function which calls your 2 existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call the `removeRed` method from inside  the `deleteInstance` method? Both methods accepts same arguments so should be painless. Put it before

```
if(confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cet enregistrement ?\nOPERATION IRREVERSIBLE'))
```